# Need to execute logic on sftp connection

Tags: shell-script, sftp

I to execute the below logic after SFTP login. My source dir is on SFTP server and destDir is a Unix server path. I have all the text and JSON files on the SFTP folder and after execution of below logic I need to `cp` all the JSON files to Unix path.

```
for jsonfile in "$sourcedir"/*.json; do
    txtfile="${jsonfile%.json}.txt"
    if [ -e "$txtfile" ]; then
        printf 'Will move %s to %s\n' "$jsonfile" "$destdir"
        cp -i "$jsonfile" "$destdir"
    fi
done
```

Comment: You may want to get all `*.json` and `*.txt` files to a local directory _first_ (using `sftp`) and then run that loop with `$sourcedir` set to that local directory.  Do you have `rsync` access to the files?

Comment: I assume the goal is that when new files appear in the SFTP source directory, you want to copy them. Investigate `inotifywatch` to be able to trigger an acction when a file is created in the watched directory.

Comment: Hi @Kusalananda/ @glenn:Yes, That is correct. I would like to copy all the json files which have corresponding text files from the sFTP server to my local unix path  and I have 777 access to the files present at sFTP location.   The motive of the above logic is to copy any new file coming at sFTP location which has corresponding text file to my local unix path. and the file which doesn't have it's corresponding text file won't be copied from sFTP to local unix path.